# DateTime issue when hour is >11

Tags: .net

I'm working on a custom date format converter and everything seems to work fine until I get an hour > 11. Currently we're using 24-hour format but I get the same behavior when I revert to 12 hr format using the long time converter. As as the hour reaches noon it formats 12 hrs behind.

```
public static string DateFormatConverter(string date)
{
    DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMddhhmmss", null);
  
    string month = result.ToLongDateString().Replace(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + ",", "");
    month = month.Replace(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), "");
    month = month.Replace(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + ",", "");
     date = result.Day.ToString() + " " + month + result.ToString("yy") + " " + result.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    date = date.Replace("  ", " ");
    return date;
}
```

Here is the input:

> 1)20230629105843
> 2)20230629124942

Here is the output:

> 1)29 June 23 10:58:43 
> 2)29 June 23 00:49:42

Comment: Would reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" help? You could e.g. replace calls to `DateTime.Now` with a custom method of yours that returns a constant `DateTime` to produce the erroneous behavior and then debug your code.

Comment: What a long-winded way of just doing `return result.ToString("dd MMMM yy HH:mm:ss");` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), `hh` is for 12 hour format, you need `HH` for 24 hour format

Comment: Thanks, I actually was there earlier, but that helped. The issue was I was using 24 hour format correctly for the substring conversion, but not for the actual format string which is used to create the datetime string. I changed this string from "yyyyMMddhhmmss" to "yyyyMMddHHmmss" and that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

So for those of you who might be facing a similar issue with .net I've posted a version of a simplified version of the function with the correction, since there was some unnecessary lines of code that I thought might confuse some people.

```
public static string DateFormatConverter(string date)
    {
        DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);
        date = result.Day.ToString() + " " + result.ToString("MMMM")+" " + result.ToString("yy") + " " + result.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        date = date.Replace("  ", " ");
        return date;
    }
```